# open google maps through intent for specific location in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-urls

I'm designing one application in which I want to show specific location on Map.
I'm passing `String` of address which is already placed on `Google Map`.
Following is my `Intent` code..

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+address;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

But it gives me Google Map for getting direction. I know why that so, because I used `daddr` in `url` but I don't know what to use for specific location..Please tell me what to use there..

Comment: hi I am developing a trip planner project, is completely free to use 'open google maps through intent for a specific location in android', or any pricing if reached quote?? do you know anything about this plz share

Comment: Its completely free to open specific location via intent as you are opening it in external App and not in yours..

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I have not tested this but you could try :

**First method:**

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**EDIT:**
This might not work with Google maps 7,0

hence you could change the uri to :

**Second option:**

```
String geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat + "," + lng + " (" + mTitle + ")";
```

where `mTitle` is the name of the location.

**Third option:**

```
geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
```

**Fourth option:**

```
String map = "http://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=" + yourAddress;
```

Hope that works and helps :D..

Comment: and what about lat and lng ? I don't want to pass them, I'm just passing address

Comment: oh alright, il have to google that part :).. like i said iv not tried this either :).. il get back

Comment: Please try, and if you get something the tell me

Comment: but i think i did read it somewhere that it would ignore the lat and long and simply take the location denoted by `mTitle`

Comment: and you could catch ur ears the other way round, get lat and long from the address and then pass those to the string uri

Comment: @Aksh hi, try `geo:0,0?q=my+street+address`

Comment: Thanks, your fourth solution worked so easily, just have to add `q` ..:)

Comment: Second one is mine. I used it without adding title and it works.

Comment: Any idea how to pass the adress to the search bar of Google Maps?

Answer (score 40):

## Get Lat-Lng Using this web-service

`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "&sensor=false`

## Then Pass it to this code

```
    String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat + "," + lng + " (" + "Label which you want" + ")";
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));

    intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");

    startActivity(intent);
```

### I hope it will help you

Thank you.

Answer (score 39):

The latest version of map provides better solution. If you wish show an address on map use below code.

```
Uri mapUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + Uri.encode(address));
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

If you want to display using latitude and longitude values, use below method.

```
Uri mapUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=lat,lng(label)");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mapUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Lat and lng being the latitude and longitude you wish to display, the label here is optional.

Comment: +1, this is the only option that doesn't explicitly mention Google Maps. The `?q=lat,lon` parameter has better results too, as it displays a pin on the opened map (the first lat,lon only pans the map to the location). The `setPackage` call is optional.

Comment: FYI, Google Maps is not displaying the value for "label" when the 2nd option you've shown is used.  I have verified that `regionData.name` is a String in the following code snippet `Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=loc:${regionData.location.latitude},${regionData.location.longitude} (${regionData.name})")`

Answer (score 8):

This will work like a charm. Make sure to check for existence for Google Maps, so this can work universally across all non Google devices also. It will open in a browser in such cases.

Also, remember, don't have www in the URL. Else this will not work.

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude));
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Only if initiating from a Broadcast Receiver
        String mapsPackageName = "com.google.android.apps.maps";
        if (isPackageExisted(context, mapsPackageName)) {
            i.setClassName(mapsPackageName, "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
            i.setPackage(mapsPackageName);
        }
        context.startActivity(i);

private static boolean isPackageExisted(Context context, String targetPackage){
    PackageManager pm=context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo(targetPackage,PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020 you can also consider using [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide), the API designed by Google in order to create universal cross-platform links. You can open Google maps on web, Android or iOS using the same URL string in form:

https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&parameters

In case when you need show certain location you can use an URL like

`https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=36.26577,-92.54324`

The code snippet is

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query="+address;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + address));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(mapIntent);
}
```

[Refer this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents)

Answer (score 2):

```
  try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + src_lat+ "," + src_lng + "&daddr=" + des_lat + "," + des_lng));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException  ane){

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Please Install Google Maps ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }catch (Exception ex){
                    ex.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

This helper method using uriBuilder for cleaner code and handle condition if there is no activity on device that can open map

```
public static boolean openMap(Context context, String address) {
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
            .scheme("geo")
            .path("0,0")
            .appendQueryParameter("q", address);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriBuilder.build());
    if (intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To show location and disply show directions button inside google Maps use
this code snippet:

```
String geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude + " (" + locationName + ")";
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUri));
if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
    context.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution in Google documentation so, it will work fine.

```
Double latitude = 37.7749,longitude = -122.4192;
            String label = "Your location desired Aryan";
            Uri gmmIntentUri =
                    Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+latitude+","+longitude+"("+label+")");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            context.startActivity(mapIntent);
```

If you have any doubt just comment it. I am not checking maps package because on every Android device we have maps. If you want you check it easily.

Answer (score 0):

For the ones, who are looking for opening the "Maps" app for a particular location(by passing lat and long) and **do not want that lat/long co-ordinates to be shown in Maps search bar** after redirection(Opening Maps app). Instead wish to show some **label** or **place name**, you can refer to the code below,

```
private void openMapView(String latitude , String longitude , String locationName){
    Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:"+latitude+","+longitude+"?q="+locationName);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(mapIntent);
    }
}
```

Note : "locationName" in the method above, represents the name you wish to display inside the Maps search bar.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I would chip in with the Kotlin code.

I created a helper function that takes `latitude`, `longitude` and `context` params to fire off the intent.

```
fun openGoogleMap(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: Context) { ... }
```

Inside the `openGoogleMap()` helper function create an **intent** passing in the **action**, **data** to act upon (*lat/long*) and **package name** for the Google Map application.

```
 fun openGoogleMap(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, context: Context) {
    
        // you need action, data and package name
    
        val uri = Uri.parse("geo:$latitude,$longitude?z=15")
        //create an intent
        val mapIntent = Intent()
    
        //add action & data
        mapIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
        mapIntent.data = uri
    
        //package name for google maps app
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
        try {
            context.startActivity(mapIntent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
    
            //if map app isn't resolved/installed catch error
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

}
```

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#intent_requests) say that

> To verify that an app is available to receive the intent, call
> resolveActivity() on your Intent object. If the result is non-null,
> there is at least one app that can handle the intent and it's safe to
> call startActivity().

But I found that using `resolveActivity()` has issues when used with this code especially when you are outside the Activity's code.

```
mapIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.let {
  ...
}
```

To get around this I used ***try-catch*** block to catch ***ActivityNotFoundException*** with startActivity().

```
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
        try {
            context.startActivity(mapIntent)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {

            //if map app isn't resolved/installed catch error
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```

I tested the util function and it does work and is launching the GoogleMaps with Kotlin code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the name and address of the location available then you can launch the exact spot along with its images, details and navigation option using the following code :

```
    fun loadLocation(ctx: Context, name: String, address: String) {
        try {
            val geoUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=$name,$address"
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoUri))
            ctx.startActivity(intent)
        }
        catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

https://www.google.com/maps/dir//37.4219983,-122.084

```
String location = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//" + latitude + "," + longitude;
try {
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault(); // using android SmsManager
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, message + location, null, null); // adding number and text
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Sms not send, please check phone number/network", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```