# Launching map Activity using Intents not working

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch maps to show particular places when a button is pressed, I thought I could use Intents however they open the map but all I see is the Google sign in the bottom left hand corner and a beige screen.

I'm new to this so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

This is the activity to launch the maps:

```
public class ShowMaps extends ActionBarActivity {

Button sot;
Button sta;
Button lic;
Button shr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_maps);
    sot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sot) ;
    sta = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sta);
    lic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lic);
    shr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shr);

    sot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ShowMaps.this, SOT.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    sta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ShowMaps.this, STA.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    lic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ShowMaps.this, LIC.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    shr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(ShowMaps.this, SHR.class);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_show_maps, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here is one of the map fragments the code is the same in all four only the Lat&Long have changed:

```
public class SOT extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sot);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sotMap))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.009066, -2.176138)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

Comment: Need some more info.  Put some code from the activity that has the maps.  Sounds like you may not have an api key, or an incorrect one.

Comment: i think you didn't have api  key

Comment: I have followed the instructions to get a key and in a separate test app the key works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [open google maps through intent for specific location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704451/open-google-maps-through-intent-for-specific-location-in-android)

So yes there is a way to open maps using Intents. It involves using URIs.

The code to do this is:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: this works great, however is there a way of doing it in the app itself without it opening the maps app itself

Comment: @NickFallows See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353255/how-to-put-google-maps-v2-on-a-fragment-using-viewpager