# Java - How to navigate to a map url in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I have a button that navigates to the map with a certain link. Here is my code:

```
Intent open2 = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

open2.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.google.com.eg/maps/dir/''/point+90+mall+location/data=!4m5!4m4!1m0!1m2!1m1!1s0x145822591a17706b:0xc9f886adcffbb941?sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF5-KS6t3SAhWoLcAKHWI-CEoQ9RcIeTAM"));

startActivity(open2);
```

But when I click from my mobile, it goes to the map. But it gives this to me:

> Cannot find the starting point

How can I fix that?

Comment: what place do you want to open in your map? Specific coordinates or a place by name?

Comment: No, by name not coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong maps query-string, try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=Point 90 Mall, Cairo Governorate"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Generally use this query `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=PLACE_NAME` where you replace the `PLACE_NAME` with the place name (or search string) of google maps.

More info here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

and here:
[open google maps through intent for specific location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704451/open-google-maps-through-intent-for-specific-location-in-android)

Comment: Thanks i will try it and tell u>

Comment: Thank you bro! it worked and another thanks for giving me these helpful link to understand how google maps work :)