# How to Open and Directing Google Maps using Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a problem to let Google Maps playing automatically after opened...

Example: I have put intent code and yes it will open Google maps according to my latitude and longitude...
But, I still need to press a button to start Google Maps to direct me.
How can I make Google Map open automatically after opened by intent without pressed by users? Is it possible ?

Here is my code,

```
private void turnOnMap()
{
    String labelMap = "Target";
    String geouri = "geo:0,0?q=-6.908572,107.610923(XXI)";
    Intent mapInt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geouri));
    startActivity(mapInt);
}
```

I got some information of intent code from these
[open google maps through intent for specific location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704451/open-google-maps-through-intent-for-specific-location-in-android)
and [Android - How to launch Google map intent in android app with certain location, zoom level and marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13053352/android-how-to-launch-google-map-intent-in-android-app-with-certain-location) and also latest uri from official android site https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

And, they don't explain what command should I add to play Google Maps automatically after opened...

Hope you can help me guys... Thank you very much for your time and information

Comment: What about the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation)?

Comment: Maybe you should read about [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action).

Comment: I got it mate... here we go https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#launch_turn-by-turn_navigation
Thank you @Eselfar for your suggestion.. works ;)
and xomena for more details information Google Map API

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + latitude + "," + longitude + " (" + yourLocationName + ")";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote if it helped you in someway

Comment: This answer is quite old - but it works where newer blogs/answers don't - thank you :D