# Launch Google Maps with explicit Intent

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to launch Google Maps from my app with an explicit intent; I dont want to navigate to a point in the map or to show any particular place in the map -- I just want to launch Google Maps.

How can I do this? Whats the Intent for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open google maps through intent for specific location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704451/open-google-maps-through-intent-for-specific-location-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/";
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

It will open **Google Map** application.

Comment: I think this is exactly what you wanted. Isn't it? @MichelReap

Answer (score 1):

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=");
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Use this above code in your button click or any other place you want to implement.

Comment: Please read the question, I specifically said *I dont want to go to any place in particular*